# Twitter Bootstrap: safe to use pseudo classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As a practice (not sure if it's good), but I've been adding a `.last` to lists of things wherein I need to select the last item. I do this because I am not confident about how `:last-child` will work across browsers.

Do I need to worry about this in Bootstrap? Or was I wrong to worry about it in the first place?

Comment: Depends on what kind of pseudo-class you're referring to.

Comment: `:lastchild` as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no :last pseudo-class in css. You may be thinking of the :last-child pseudo-class, which is supported in IE8 and up, as well as all modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, as well as modern mobile browsers.

Twitter Bootstrap was made as a starting point, and so long as IE7 support is not a concern, using pseudo-classes like :last-child is safe. Be sure to reference the specific pseudo classes browser support though. Here's a nice list: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

**EDIT: I had first-child and last-child mixed up, last-child is ie9 and up.**

Comment: So nothing magical happens in Bootstrap to make me not have to worry about this?

Comment: Bolt is right, I mixed up first-child and last-child. In answer, bootstrap does not add a polyfill for the last-child pseudo class.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this javascript plugin:
http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: Don't want to use JS. I added a class `.last` and select things that way. Works well; no JS needed.